# GTK: display a tooltip for a gtkButton in a gtkFixed container with gtkImage as background

Tags: r, gtk, gtk2

I want to position a gtkButton on top of a gtkImage. I do this putting both inside a gtkFixed container. The problem now is that the button's tooltip is not shown anymore, when there is an image in the background. Without the image it works fine. How can I get the tooltip to be shown?

I am an R programmer so the below code is R-Gtk binding style, but should still convey the idea:

```
library(RGtk2)
w = gtkWindow() 
image = gtkImage(file="tmp_1.png")
btn = gtkButton("Test")
gtkWidgetSetTooltipText(btn, "test")
fx = gtkFixed()
gtkFixedPut(fx, image, 10, 10)   
gtkFixedPut(fx, btn, 10,10)
gtkContainerAdd(w, fx)
gtkWidgetShowAll(w)
```

Any ideas?
TIA.

Comment: Do you want to have an image in the button? Won't [`gtk_button_set_image`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkButton.html#gtk-button-set-image) suffice? Or is it missing in R-Gtk bindings?

Comment: What I want is an image as a background that contains visual information and gets redrawn periodically. On top of the image I want to place several buttons (or other widgets). I do not need images or icons in the buttons themselves. All this works fine, except for the tooltips...

Comment: Maybe you want an image background for the container (in this case GtkFixed).  In such case, you can see a [hint in PyGTK FAQ](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=all#8.21).  You can update the background whenever you want and it should not interfere with the events for the widgets on top of the container.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [**GtkOverlay**](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkOverlay.html) widget. You add your GtkImage widget as main child of the overlay and the button with [**gtk_overlay_add_overlay**](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkOverlay.html#gtk-overlay-add-overlay).

That should work, and that's the preferred way of doing it.